# How to prevent inspect element value on submit in php

Tags: php, wordpress, form-submit

i faced very weird issue in my web.

i make a product page and its price. When i go to cart and submit the paypal, it submit  perfectly but when i get inspect element and change the value the value of input has been changed and when i submit the button the inspected value submited.

i do somthing in code but nothing happen

here is my code

```
    function wp_paypal_product($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'prodname' => 'no value'
                    ), $atts));

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'paypal_products';
    $prodname = str_replace('-', ' ', $prodname);
    $shorcode_product = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE product_name ='$prodname'");
    $product_name = $shorcode_product->product_name;
    $product_price = $shorcode_product->product_price;
    $product_id = $shorcode_product->id;
    $paypalID = get_option('paypalID');
    $currency = get_option('currency');
    $upload_image = get_option('upload_image');
    $return_url = get_option('return_url');
    $email_subject = get_option('email_subject');
    $email_message = get_option('email_message');

    if (!$upload_image) {
        $upload_image = 'http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif';
    }

    $output = $product_name . '<br>'
            . $product_price . '<br>'
            . $paypalID . '<br>'
            . $currency . '<br>'
            . $upload_image . '<br>'
            . $return_url . '<br>'
            . $email_subject . '<br>'
            . $email_message . '<br>';

    $output = '<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="' . $paypalID . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="' . $return_url . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="' . $currency . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . $product_name . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $product_price . '">
        <input name="notify_url" value="' . plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'ipn.php" type="hidden">
        <input type="image" src="' . $upload_image . '" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!"> 
        </form>';

    return $output;
}


add_shortcode('wp-paypal-product', 'wp_paypal_product');
```

How can i prevent the inspected value on submit......PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: you can't. You have to check the values server side.

Comment: Are product information coming from database? if yes, do not post price, just use product id and fetch information each time from database. Or you can save cart information into SESSION when user click on "add to cart" button.

Comment: Do not ever bother price which is transmitted via the Internet. Just POST the product IDs and get the price from your Database. Or if you really need to transfer the price, instead of POST store it ins SESSION variables and retrieve. BUT REMEMBER SESSION VARIABLES TOO BIT DANGER.

Comment: But how can i give the price in paypal....because paypal give us form and put this form in it

Comment: Encrypt the data and send to the PayPal. More details can be found here -> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/ewp-techview-outside

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS can you give me link for ipn ... you gave me link is for individual buttons

Comment: Bro can you post your complete code............

Comment: See the question now deemi....i edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is for every one you can prevent data save in Inspect Element....this work 100000% work.

This is very helpful for online shoping

Now you can put jQuery code after your Form.

Like this

```
$output = '<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="' . $paypalID . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="' . $return_url . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="' . $currency . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . $product_name . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="p'.$product_id.'" value="' . $product_price . '">
        <input name="notify_url" value="' . plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'ipn.php" type="hidden">
        <input type="image" src="' . $upload_image . '" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!"> 
        </form>';

    $output .= "<script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        var a=".$product_price.";
                        jQuery('form[name=_xclick]').submit(function(c){
                            var b=jQuery('input[id=p".$product_id."]').val();
                            if(b==a){
                                return
                            }else{
                                c.preventDefault()
                            }
                        })
                    });
                </script>";

    return $output;
```

First we make an id in price text field.
We save price from DB in jQuery.
Then we call a form on submit save a value of amount text field.
Then we check if DB value and amount value is same then it proceed else it stop.

if any on can change the value of amount in inspect element, then the form is not submited.

Hope this will help you.

But you should know that, using this method, a determined attacker could still change your prices, even though joe user might not be able to inspect element. So a better option would be to only submit the product id and use a server side process to communicate with PayPal.

Comment: Thanx alot deemi thanx alot thank u thank u you solved my problem.......its work perfectly in browser inspect element. +1

Comment: Its my pleasure to help u

Comment: This is completely useless. Turn off JavaScript and you're back at square one.

Comment: And don't forget that you can modify the POST data not only in the browser, but in a proxy application too. You should NOT use POST data for this.

Comment: And btw, you don't even need to turn off JavaScript in the browser ... you only have to change `a` in the developer tools to the same value as the field `amount`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent that. The correct way would be to only transmit the id of the product to the server and read the price from the database before adding it to the cart. Or, even better, only store the ID in the cart and read the price from the database when you display the cart.

Do not rely on POST data when you transmit crucial data, there are just too many ways the user can modify it. If you use JavaScript to prevent the submit of a form that has been tempered with, the user can just disable JavaScript. Or he can use a proxy application ([Paros](http://sourceforge.net/projects/paros/), [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_WebScarab_Project) are examples of proxy apps that are designed to analyze and modify HTTP requests and responses between the browser and the server) to modify the POST data before it is actually transmitted.

Only store crucial data in a session.

Comment: But how can i give the price in paypal....because paypal give us form and put this form in it

Comment: I'm pretty sure paypal has a documentation for this.

Comment: have you link of paypal documentation

Comment: What if business info is changed? E.g if someone changed merchant paypal id to his own.